# Which version of facebook graph api am I using?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

At thef8 event, Graph API v2.0 was introduced. I have integrated the graph api on my website, but I want to find out which of the version I am currently using.

Is there a method or a way to find out this?

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34471722/4484799

Answer (score 4):

To make a call to a versioned API, simply append /[version] to the API call after the host name. To call version "v2.0", use "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/". Versions are guaranteed to be available for minimum 2 yrs after they are released.

Unversioned Calls: Unversioned API calls point to the oldest available version of the API.

So if your app makes unversioned calls, then you are using the oldest graph API.

For more info see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions

Comment: If you found this answer useful, please click the arrow up.

Comment: This the Profile URL I am using  "https://graph.facebook.com/<FB_UID>?access_token=<FB_ACCESS_TOKEN>", so which version do you think I am using?

Comment: I don't think this answered the question. I too would like to know if there is a way to programmatically show what version of the graph api is installed. For example, it is possible to show the Facebook SDK version with [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion].  If not programmatically, then is there some indication in any of the SDK headers?