# How can i find out facebook API version

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an app id and secret of a facebook app. But I am not owner, how can I find out its app version?

I tried to go through fb graph api document but it did not work.

Comment: I don't _think_ you can tell the version from just the application ID and secret; you'd have to look at the API call (since the URIs contain the API version being used)

Comment: @ChrisForrence To get user information, the API call is `https://graph.facebook.com/{fb-id}?access_token={token}` I didn't see the version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to a somewhat relatable [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#upgrade), you can check the `facebook-api-version` header in the response to determine the API version that had been used to process the request.

Currently (as of December 26, 2015), the oldest active version is 2.0, so any unversioned calls will use the 2.0 API (until August 2016). The changelog can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)